# Construct a primitive type directly on the heap in Go?

Tags: go, memory-management, initialization, heap-memory, literals

How do I construct a primitive integer type directly on the heap in Go?

For composite literals, the [following syntax](http://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#composite_literals) is supported:

```
return &File{fd, name, nil, 0}
```

But no such equivalent seems to exist for `int` and friends:

```
Size: &uint64(entry.FileInfo.Size()),
```

> d:\gopath\src\bitbucket.org\anacrolix\dms\dlna\dms\dms.go:271: cannot take the address of uint64(entry.FileInfo.Size())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> [Address operators](http://golang.org/ref/spec#Address_operators)
>
> For an operand x of type T, the address operation &x generates a
>   pointer of type *T to x. The operand must be addressable, that is,
>   either a variable, pointer indirection, or slice indexing operation;
>   or a field selector of an addressable struct operand; or an array
>   indexing operation of an addressable array. As an exception to the
>   addressability requirement, x may also be a composite literal.

Primitive integer types are not addressable. If the integer is a register variable, there is no memory address. If the integer is a constant, providing its memory address would allow it to be modified.

Therefore, create an integer type variable and take its address or use an integer pointer type. For example,

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    var i int = 42
    var pi = &i
    j := int(7)
    pj := &j
    var pk = new(int)
    k := *pk
    fmt.Println(i, pi)
    fmt.Println(j, pj)
    fmt.Println(k, pk)
}
```

Output:

```
42 0xf840043100
7 0xf840043108
0 0xf840043110
```

Answer (score 1):

Initializing a pointer to a type using `new`, always allocates it on the heap.

```
n := new(int64)
*n = entry.FileInfo.Size()
return &n
```

You can also just take the address of a stack allocated integer.
When returning a pointer to a stack allocated object, Go's escape analysis will ensure this object is promoted to the heap. While this does not immediately allocate it on the heap, it will end up there.

```
n := entry.FileInfo.Size()
return &n
```

As to your question on why the `&T{}` approach does not work for primitives, I seem to have forgot. I do know there was a good reason for it, but perhaps someone more knowledgeable can enlighten us on this matter.